# Django postgres database connectivity - DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have tried many options available however nothing is worked for me.

This is my environment

- OS : Windows 10 Home  64bit
- Python Version : Python 3.9.0a6
- Django Version : 3.0.5
- Postgress db Version : 12

This is the method I used to make the connectivity

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxxx',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

**Error**  that I'm receiving :

```
(dev-test) F:\Personal\xxxx\Learning\Django\projects\jangoproject\devtest>python manage.py startserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\dev-test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Envs\dev-test\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the command

```
pip install django psycopg2 
'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'PORT'  : ' '
```

So the default port is selected

Comment: Hi, Thanks. but it didn't work for me I'm hitting the same error. I have already install above mention  packages before test this out.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 with `conda` environment manager (fresh install of `Django`, `wagtail` with `PostgreSQL`), had the same error. Removed `psycopg2`

```
conda remove -n myenv psycopg2
```

it updated some packages, removed others (it also removed django, wagtail... on its own). Then installed `psycopg2` back

```
conda install -n myenv psycopg2
```

Tested it, import worked

```
python
>>> import psycopg2
```

Installed `django`, `wagtail` back. `python manage.py migrate` now populated `PostgreSQL`. Maybe the reason was that psycopg2 was installed after django and wagtail, this reversed the installation order.